# Same TypeOrm code Code Executing differently on local and dev environment

Tags: javascript, postgresql, typeorm, serverless-framework

I am using typeorm with express and serverless js. I am using postgres DB and I am using same DB on both sandbox(local) and dev env. I am trying to upsert a model and from logs I see that different queries are being run on sandbox and dev env although the model and everything is same and a insert query is throwing error on dev env and the insert query is not being run on my sandbox env while doing the upsert.

Here are the logs

```
Sandbox Environment:

query: SELECT "provider_addresses"."id" AS "id", "provider_addresses"."provider_id" AS "provider_id" FROM "wsp"."provider_addresses" "provider_addresses" WHERE (("provider_addresses"."provider_id" = $1)) -- PARAMETERS: [1858]
```

```
query: SELECT "provider_phonenumbers"."id" AS "id", "provider_phonenumbers"."provider_id" AS "provider_id" FROM "wsp"."provider_phonenumbers" "provider_phonenumbers" WHERE (("provider_phonenumbers"."provider_id" = $1)) -- PARAMETERS: [1858]
```

```
query: SELECT "provider_socialmedia"."id" AS "id", "provider_socialmedia"."provider_id" AS "provider_id" FROM "wsp"."provider_socialmedia" "provider_socialmedia" WHERE (("provider_socialmedia"."provider_id" = $1)) -- PARAMETERS: [1858]
```

```
query: START TRANSACTION
```

```
query: UPDATE "wsp"."providers" SET "modified_date" = $1 WHERE "id" IN ($2) -- PARAMETERS: ["2024-01-11T19:23:38.156Z",1858]
```

```
query: COMMIT
```

```
On Dev Environment:
2024-01-11T19:10:46.657Z    a2f0b273-5339-48e8-ad0c-e6378c75a989    INFO    query: SELECT "provider_addresses"."id" AS "id", "provider_addresses"."provider_id" AS "provider_id" FROM "wsp"."provider_addresses" "provider_addresses" WHERE (("provider_addresses"."provider_id" = $1)) -- PARAMETERS: [1858]

2024-01-11T19:10:46.658Z    a2f0b273-5339-48e8-ad0c-e6378c75a989    INFO    query: SELECT "provider_phonenumbers"."id" AS "id", "provider_phonenumbers"."provider_id" AS "provider_id" FROM "wsp"."provider_phonenumbers" "provider_phonenumbers" WHERE (("provider_phonenumbers"."provider_id" = $1)) -- PARAMETERS: [1858]

2024-01-11T19:10:46.659Z    a2f0b273-5339-48e8-ad0c-e6378c75a989    INFO    query: SELECT "provider_socialmedia"."id" AS "id", "provider_socialmedia"."provider_id" AS "provider_id" FROM "wsp"."provider_socialmedia" "provider_socialmedia" WHERE (("provider_socialmedia"."provider_id" = $1)) -- PARAMETERS: [1858]

2024-01-11T19:10:46.669Z    a2f0b273-5339-48e8-ad0c-e6378c75a989    INFO    query: START TRANSACTION

2024-01-11T19:10:46.679Z    a2f0b273-5339-48e8-ad0c-e6378c75a989    INFO    query: INSERT INTO "wsp"."provider_phonenumbers"("created_by", "created_date", "modified_by", "modified_date", "user_id", "phone_number", "provider_id", "extension", "phone_type", "dialing_code", "is_primary", "is_verified", "verified_date") VALUES (DEFAULT, $1, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, $2, $3, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, $4, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT) RETURNING "id", "is_primary", "is_verified" -- PARAMETERS: ["2024-01-11T19:10:46.673Z","6466853761",1858,"+1"]

2024-01-11T19:10:46.686Z    a2f0b273-5339-48e8-ad0c-e6378c75a989    INFO    query failed: INSERT INTO "wsp"."provider_phonenumbers"("created_by", "created_date", "modified_by", "modified_date", "user_id", "phone_number", "provider_id", "extension", "phone_type", "dialing_code", "is_primary", "is_verified", "verified_date") VALUES (DEFAULT, $1, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, $2, $3, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, $4, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT) RETURNING "id", "is_primary", "is_verified" -- PARAMETERS: ["2024-01-11T19:10:46.673Z","6466853761",1858,"+1"]
```

Need Help with the discrepancies.

I tried everthing. Synced all the dependencies like my common packages which contain code for type orm entities on both the envs but to no avail.